# How do I download a rule yaml file directly?

Tags: semgrep

Is there a way to download a Semgrep rule's yaml file from providing the rule name id? I know that you can bring them manually from the registry (via copy/paste).. but I am looking for a faster way so I can test rules locally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to find all rule yaml files from Semgrep is through the [Semgrep Rules Github Repository](https://github.com/returntocorp/semgrep-rules). You can use the rule-id to search for it using the **"Go to file"** button within the repo:

["Go to file button within repo"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OBRbt.png)

["Searching for rules via rule-id"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h55bo.png).

Once you have located the rule you wish to download, right-click on the **"Raw"** button and then click **"Save link as..."** to download the yaml file directly.

["Rule yaml file within repo"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TdC9J.png)