# Download Full Semgrep Ruleset / Multiple rules in one file

Tags: semgrep

I want to run semgrep cli as step in my ci pipeline without internet access.
So far I understand that i need to turn off metrics, version check and have the rules as yaml file.
I got this to work by downloading a rule file, adding it to the mount and pointing to it in the --config parameter.

Is there an elegant way to download a ruleset from the website? [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72261717/how-do-i-download-a-rule-yaml-file-directly/72261789#72261789) somebody explained how to download them from a git repository, however it's still plenty of work to choose all the right rules and put them all in a single file.

I feel I am missing some obvious option here, where I can simply take the default rulesets and get it as a yaml file or I totally missunderstood the intended workflow. Is there a simpler way?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.